# YouTube PHP API Besides Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube

I'm currently using the Zend Framework YouTube PHP Api but under high load Zend just doesn't perform that well. Even when implementing caching each Youtube Video object is about 23kb compressed. I'd rather switch to another implementation of the API. Are there any other maintained implementations? I've searched but it's a little difficult to find.

Comment: How high is 'high'? size wise, 23kb for an object doesn't seem like much. How many videos per page are you loading? Are you querying youtube over and over again? Are you caching results?

Answer (score 1):

I recently ported my CodeIgniter YouTube API implementation to regular PHP. You can find it here: https://github.com/jimdoescode/Zendless-PHP-YouTube-API

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure google has a non-Zend PHP implementation of the YouTube API.  If you're looking for more speed, I would try a different language.  Python may be a good way to go, though the other implementations are here:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/code.html

Comment: This is embedded within a PHP application so I do need to stick with PHP. Thanks for the suggestion though